# Orchard import from batch

Tags: batch-file, import, automation, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to periodically import some data in Orchard CMS.

I would automate the task so that I send the files via ftp in a special folder (maybe just a sbufolder of App_data) and Orchard automagically sees that a file was there, runs the recipe and the deletes the file (or moves it in some way so that it does not process it twice).

Is there something already in Orchard that can be used for this task or should I create something new for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the feature/deployment branch. It's not fully baked, but it's made to automate repeated content transfers.